# Uri getting null for Android 11 (R)

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, android-11

I want to create sub directory (custom folder) with text file and write string data in it. As in `Android 11` there is restriction so i have done this code.

```
private val filepath = "mySubDirectory"
private val filename = "test.txt"

private fun writeExternalStorage(list: MutableList<String>) {
    if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        val resolver = contentResolver
        val values = ContentValues()
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, filename)
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "text/plain")
        values.put(
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH,
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS + "/" + filepath
        )
        val uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"), values)
        Log.v("MYATGAGAA", uri!!.toString())
        val file = FileUtil.from(this, uri!!) as File
        Log.v("MYATGAGAA", file.absolutePath)
        try {
            file.parentFile.mkdirs()
            file.bufferedWriter().use { out ->
                for (item in list) {
                    Log.v("MYATGAGAA", item)
                    out.write(item)
                }
            }

        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error Q", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            return

        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "Saved for Q", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()


      }
```

But i m getting uri `null` at this line `Log.v("MYATGAGAA", uri!!.toString())`

I have already granted storage permission below:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

For `Android R` devices i have manually checked

```
if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        try {
            val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION)
            intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT")
            intent.data =
                Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s", applicationContext.packageName))
            startActivityForResult(intent, 2296)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            val intent = Intent()
            intent.action = Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION
            startActivityForResult(intent, 2296)
        }
    }
```

This is my *FileUtil* class.

```
class FileUtil {

companion object {

    private const val EOF = -1
    private const val DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 4

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun from(context: Context, uri: Uri): File? {
        val inputStream: InputStream = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)!!
        val fileName = getFileName(context, uri)
        val splitName = splitFileName(fileName)
        var tempFile: File = File.createTempFile(splitName[0], splitName[1])
        tempFile = rename(tempFile, fileName)
        tempFile.deleteOnExit()
        var out: FileOutputStream? = null
        try {
            out = FileOutputStream(tempFile)
        } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        if (inputStream != null) {
            copy(inputStream, out!!)
            inputStream.close()
        }
        out?.close()
        return tempFile
    }

    private fun splitFileName(fileName: String): Array<String> {
        var name = fileName
        var extension = ""
        val i = fileName.lastIndexOf(".")
        if (i != -1) {
            name = fileName.substring(0, i)
            extension = fileName.substring(i)
        }
        return arrayOf(name, extension)
    }

    private fun getFileName(context: Context, uri: Uri): String {
        var result: String? = null
        if (uri.scheme.equals("content")) {
            val cursor: Cursor = context.contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null)!!
            try {
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    result =
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME))
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            } finally {
                if (cursor != null) {
                    cursor.close()
                }
            }
        }
        if (result == null) {
            result = uri.path
            val cut: Int = result!!.lastIndexOf(File.separator)
            if (cut != -1) {
                result = result.substring(cut + 1)
            }
        }
        return result
    }

    private fun rename(file: File, newName: String): File {
        val newFile = File(file.parent, newName)
        if (newFile != file) {
            if (newFile.exists() && newFile.delete()) {
                Log.d("FileUtil", "Delete old $newName file")
            }
            if (file.renameTo(newFile)) {
                Log.d("FileUtil", "Rename file to $newName")
            }
        }
        return newFile
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun copy(input: InputStream, output: OutputStream): Long {
        var count: Long = 0
        var n: Int
        val buffer = ByteArray(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)
        while (EOF != input.read(buffer).also { n = it }) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, n)
            count += n.toLong()
        }
        return count
    }
}
}
```

still getting error. So please help me to sort out this. Thanks in Advance

Comment: add this  android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" in your manifest inside the application.

Comment: I have already added this in manifest file.

Comment: did you add provider paths?

Comment: _FileProvider_ path ??

Comment: yes the fileprovider

Comment: No. I did not that. Let me add and check

Comment: ok sure let me know it that helps.

Comment: I have added still getting same error.

Comment: share the error

Comment: In my above code i m not able see _test.txt_ in my _mySubDirectory_ folder. _mySubDirectory_ is created but not text file. It is _java.lang.NullPointerException_

Comment: `But i m getting uri null at this line Log.v("MYATGAGAA", uri!!.toString())` No. insert() returns null.  So you get it from insert() and val uri == null. All code you posted after that line is irrelevant and only confusing. You better remove all that code. and the subject should be that MediaStore.insert() returns null instead of a valid uri.

Comment: As a next remark i have to say that if you got a nice uri that you start messing around with a file util class and using the File class. That is not the idea of using the media store. Use the uri directly to open streams. No File class anymore.

Comment: Does your code work for an Android 10 device?

Comment: No. It doesn't work at all. Also i need to convert uri to file so i have implemented _FileUtil_ class

Comment: For what do you need to convert an uri to file? I see no reason. If you need a FIle instance then do not use the media store.

Comment: But in Android 11 there is restriction. I m not able to crate my sub directory as i have granted permissions. That's why i used _MediaStore_

Comment: If i  don't use _MediaStore_ then it is working good till _Android10_ but in Android11 i m not able to see my directory in "/Android/data/mypackagename".

Comment: `"/Android/data/mypackagename"` You mean in `"/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/mypackagename` That is an app specific path and you cannot use the media store to create files there. But you are not trying that either as you try to let the media store insert an uri for `/storage/emulated/0/Documents/mySubDirectory/test.txt`. Well that should be possible.

Comment: And now realise: If you let the media store create an uri for that path and then try to convert that uri to that path you could better start with that path yourself omitting the whole media store. I said that before.

Comment: Yes but _Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory_ kinda is deprecated for latest os version

Comment: Deprecated yes but it works fine so use it. `But in Android 11 there is restriction. I m not able to crate my sub directory ` Well you can. You can just use `new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "mySubDirectory").mkdir()` for that.